# How do I impliment IHttpRequestFeature in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net

I use kestrel.

[Reference](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/request-features.html)

Do you have a specific example of the implementation?

Answer (score 2):

I used it to find the request path of a ASP.NET Core API controller:

```
var httpFeatures = HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpRequestFeature>();

 if (httpFeatures == null)
 {
    string path = httpFeatures.Path;
  }
```

returns path "/api/client/ipaddress/islocal"

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.features.ihttprequestfeature

Comment: you mean httpFeatures != null